# Firebase auth: cannot detect user on other pages after even after auth/ login

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

While my auth code is working fine on login and signup pages, I cannot detect the logged in user on any other page:

My login Code:

```
onAuthStateChanged(auth, async(user)=> {
    if(user){
         logOutBtn.style.display = "block";
        console.log(user)
        // location.replace("stage0.html")
    }
    else{
        logOutBtn.style.display = "none";
    }
})

setPersistence(auth, browserLocalPersistence)
  .then(() => {
    console.log("Persistence successfully set to  local")
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    // Handle errors if persistence couldn't be set
    console.error('Error setting persistence:', error);
  });

const logInClicked = async()=>{
    const logInEmail= document.getElementById("login-email").value;
    const logInPassword = document.getElementById("login-password").value;
    await signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, logInEmail, logInPassword)
    .then((userCredential)=>{
        const user=auth.currentUser
        console.log(user)
        if(!user.emailVerified){
            alert("Please verify email before signing in.\nCheck your registered email for the link");
            signOut(auth);
        }
        else{
            alert("You have been Logged In");
        }
    })
    .catch((error=>{
        console.log(error)
        alert(error)
    }))
}
```

Code checking for user on other page:

```
import{ getAuth, onAuthStateChanged, signOut} from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.5.0/firebase-auth.js";
const auth = getAuth();
console.log(auth)

const user = auth.currentUser;
console.log(user)

onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user)=> {
    if(user){
        console.log("inside if:user")
        alert("you are logged in")
        // location.replace("stage0.html")
        logOutBtn.style.display = "block";
    }
    else{
        console.log("inside else: user")
        logOutBtn.style.display = "none";
        alert("Please Log In to continue")
        //location.replace("login.html")
    }
})
```

the code is returning the user as "null"!

I have tried setPersistence, but it wasn't of much use. I have also tried various things with onAuthStateChanged, experimented with async and all that